# How to ListView VCL collapse / expand by code?

Tags: listview, delphi, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Delphi 10.1 and VCL. How to collapse or expand all or specific Groups by code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expansion state is in the group's [`State`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListGroup.State) property. For instance, to collapse the first group:

```
ListView1.Groups[0].State := ListView1.Groups[0].State + [lgsCollapsed];
```

There is no shortcut for processing all groups at once.  You have to loop through them one at a time:

```
for I := 0 to ListView1.Groups.Count-1 do
begin
  ListView1.Groups[I].State := ListView1.Groups[I].State + [lgsCollapsed];
end;
```

Comment: Thanks.It is recommended to start with ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate, the colapse/expand command and complete by ListView1.Items.EndUpdate

Comment: Reron you'd put those around the loop, not inside. @Remy only posted an iteration example.